# How I can rename elements in a column vector according to the starting name in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| names | value |
| --- | --- |
| John123abc | 1 |
| George12894xyz | 2 |
| Mary789qwe | 3 |

I want to rename all the name values of the column "names" and keep only the names (not the extra numbers and characters that its name has). Imagine that the code for each name changes and I have 100.000 rows.I thing that something like starts_with("John") ="John")

Ideally i want the new data frame to look like this:

| names | value |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| George | 2 |
| Mary | 3 |

How I can do this in R using dplyr?

```
library(tidyverse)
names = c("John123abc","George12894xyz","Mary789qwe")
value = c(1,2,3)

dat = tibble(names,value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strings::str_remove` you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

names = c("John123abc","George12894xyz","Mary789qwe")
value = c(1,2,3)

dat = tibble(names,value)

dat |> 
  mutate(names = str_remove(names, "\\d+.*$"))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   names  value
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 John       1
#> 2 George     2
#> 3 Mary       3
```

Comment: For the posted problem it works.But in my real data set I get an error `! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.`

Comment: Yeah. But that's a different issue. You can't do any operations in the tidyverse when your dataframe has multiple columns with the same name, i.e. to fix that you have rename your columns so that the names are unique.

Comment: I will post a new one.Thank you for your answer

Comment: Check `janitor::clean_names`. That's my first go-to-guy to get clean column names and which ensures that column names are unique, i.e. it will add a suffix to duplicated names.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
dat$names <- trimws(dat$names, whitespace = "\\d+.*")
```

-output

```
> dat
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  names  value
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 John       1
2 George     2
3 Mary       3
```